# Execute multiple Steps for entries in a List in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I try to load a list from a txt.file and then want to execute multiple task on every single entry. Unfortunately the tasks are executed only on one entry instead of all of them.

I load the list from the txt.file with this function:

```
def load_dir_file():
    directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    filename = os.path.join(directory, "law_dir")

    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fin:
        dir_file = fin.readlines()
        return dir_file
```

This is the code to execute those tasks

```
def create_html():
    dir_lst = load_dir_file()

    for dir_link_dirty in dir_lst:
        dir_link = dir_link_dirty.replace('"',"").replace(",","").replace("\n","")
        dir_link_code = urllib.request.urlopen(dir_link)
        bs_dir_link_code = BeautifulSoup(dir_link_code, "html5lib")
        h2_a_tag = bs_dir_link_code.h2.a
        html_link = str(dir_link) + "/" + str(h2_a_tag["href"])
        print(dir_lst)
        return html_link
```

The txt. file looks like this now:

```
"https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/ao_1977",
"https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bbg_2009",
"https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bdsg_2018"
```

I am new to programming and probably fail some very basic points up there. So if you want to add some recommendation how i can improve basically, I would more then appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for general review and critique of a working piece of code?

Comment: @Brian sorry i missed the actual problem :D

Comment: Thanks for the edit! What do you want `create_html` to return? As written, it returns the `html_link` produced during the first iteration of the for loop. None of the other entries in `dir_list` are processed because the function is returning prematurely.

Comment: I want `create_html` to return a link like this: "https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/ao_1977/BJNR006130976.html" 

when i say `print(html_link)` i get every single link like i want it to, but if i want the function to return them it is only one of them. How can I return them all to work with them in a different function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment above it sounds like you want to return a list of html links not just one.  To do that you need that function to build a list and have it return that list.  You have a lot going on in `create_html`, so for illustration purposes I split that function into two: `create_html_link_list` and `create_html_link`.

```
def create_html_link(dir_link_dirty):
   dir_link = dir_link_dirty.replace('"',"").replace(",","").replace("\n","")
   dir_link_code = urllib.request.urlopen(dir_link)
   bs_dir_link_code = BeautifulSoup(dir_link_code, "html5lib")
   h2_a_tag = bs_dir_link_code.h2.a
   html_link = str(dir_link) + "/" + str(h2_a_tag["href"])

   return html_link

def create_html_link_list():
   dir_lst = load_dir_file()
   html_link_list = [
      create_html_link(dir_link_dirty)
      for dir_link_dirty in dir_lst
   ]

   return html_link_list
```

Comment: PyCharm tells me that i have to move the first "[" of `html_link_lst` up one line to the "=". Then it should work for me. Thank you!